# Ruby: Twitter API: Get All followers

Tags: ruby, twitter

Anyone have any idea why the next cursor isn't changing in the below code?

```
cursor = "-1"
followerIds = []
while cursor != 0 do
 followers = Twitter.follower_ids("IDTOLOOKUP",{"cursor"=>cursor})

 cursor = followers.next_cursor
 followerIds+= followers.ids
 sleep(2)
end
```

After the first iteration where cursor = -1, it gets assigned the nextcursor from the twitter api. However, when this is sent to the twitter API on subsequent iterations, I get the same response back as I did the first time.. with the same next_cursor.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'm using the twitter gem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit: [Suggestion regarding being rate limited removed]

The problem is the cursor option to follow_ids. It should read:

```
followers = Twitter.follower_ids("IDTOLOOKUP",{:cursor=>cursor})
```

Note the use of symbol, not string. In the original code, the "cursor" option being provided was being ignored and follower_ids was doing the default behavior, namely returning the first page of followers.

Comment: Thought that initially too. But nope. Plenty left.

Comment: YES! Thanks man, coming to this from the C# world so still ironing out the kinks in my syntax knowledge. Great that I can end this coding session with a solved problem. :-)